# Как заменить или увеличить стандартные иконки в jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, вёрстка, css

Нужна небольшая помощь...
Хотелось бы заменить или увеличить стандартные иконки в jquery ui. Как это сделать?

Comment: css классу `.ui-icon {}` или `.ui-li-icon {}` ширину и высоту задать не пробовал ?

Comment: Не желает меняться...

Comment: @Wolf Light, ну, на форуме пишут так:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-larger-icons-30x30-in-listviews

Comment: Изменения этих параметров приводиь к тому, что изменяется либо область выбора на картинке с иконками, либо ни к чему не ведет.

Comment: @Wolf Light, так там же спрайты, их нужно заменить :) в папке images иконки ведь.

Comment: А стандартные растянуть не получиться?

Comment: Возможно, дело в приоритетах стилей? Добавлять !important пробовали к .ui-icon или .ui-li-icon?

Comment: На вашем месте я бы уже взял те же `fontawesome` и не парился бы с вопросами :)